# Gitlab CI runner not taking the environmental variable of the local system

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running a simple hello world python program in gitlab ci. While running it in pipeline it throws the error python not used as the name of a cmdlet.

here is my yml file

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: always
stages:
    - Test
    - Build
Test_stage:
   tags:
        - PC_RUNNER
   stage: Test
   script:
        - echo "Test stage started"
        - cd .\test\test
        - python hello.py
```

and here is the error

```
$ cd .\test\test
$ python helloworld.py
python : The naming "python" was not used as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
program recognized. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is correct (if included), and
repeat the process.
In C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script3952941328\script.ps1:235 characters:1
+ python helloworld.py
+~~~
    + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But when i change the command and give the full path where my python is installed it works

```
    script:
        - echo "Test stage started"
        - cd .\test\test
        - C:\users\abc\python\python.exe hello.py
```

I have added the environmental paths correctly as i have already double checked it. From the Gitlab documentation i came to know that we can also add environment variable in gitlab runner TOML file which i did as follows

```
    executor = "shell"
    shell = "powershell"
    environment = ["ENV=C:\users\abc\python\", "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8"]
```

But the gitlab pipeline still throws the above error. Does someone knows what am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your path name in `environment = ["ENV=C:users\abc\python\", "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8"]`. It should be c:\users not c:users

Comment: That was a typo. But the path is correct in the config.toml file.

Comment: I think you have to set the `PATH` variable and not the `ENV`. Please try `environment = ["PATH=C:\users\abc\python\"]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working, because the runner is executed with other access right than your user. Please try to install python to a path everyone has access.